# how can i append data to file line by line in robot framework

Tags: file, append, robotframework

```
@{data} a,b,c,d,e,f

FOR ${data} IN  @{data}
    
${str1} =   Append To File  D:\\Robot\\file\\asdf.txt   ${data} encoding=UTF-8

END
```

in  file "asdf.txt" it is printing like this-> abcdef
But i want to print like this line by line

a

b

c

d

e

f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put \n after ${data} will solve your issue,

```
FOR    ${data}    IN    @{data}
    ${str1}=    Append to file    ${CURDIR}\\asdf.txt    ${data}\n
END
```